# Mac OSX Bash Script stop processing while specific window is open

Tags: bash, macos

I actually wrote a script that is compiling my LaTeX files and open the generated PDF in a viewer. That works fine.

```
cd Documents/my-bachelor-thesis/
latexmk 000_Root_Bachelor_Thesis.tex -pdf
open 000_Root_Bachelor_Thesis.pdf

ps -A | grep -m1 vorschau | awk '{print $1}'
```

So with the last line I get the PID of the process my PDF is opened.

There is the problem: I want stop my script process at the point the PDF is open. After I click on the close sign of the viewer, the process should continuo automatically. Is that somehow possible.

Current solution: I interrupt the process while waiting for some user input. After i type in something the process goes on.

```
echo "Can I proceed?"
    read input

... more script
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

Not familar with `open` in OSX.  Quick search on [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) suggests that you can force `open` to start new application, and wait until it finish by

```
open -Wn 000_Root_Bachelor_Thesis.pdf
```

Options:

> `-W`    Wait until the applications exit (even if they were already open). Use with the -n flag to allow open to function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment variable.
>
> `-n`    Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.